# Changed text value based on rollover from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, actionscript-3

I am looking to have a list of images and when you roll over one of those images it should update a some text on the page found inside of a UL.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="columns small-12 medium-9 large-10 no-padding-right">
    <div id="content-4" class="content light">
        <ul id="bottom-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="thumbnails/img1.jpg" alt="img 1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="thumbnails/img2.jpg" alt="img 1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="thumbnails/img3.jpg" alt="img 1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="thumbnails/img4.jpg" alt="img 1"></a></li>        
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="columns small-12 medium-9 large-10 no-padding-right text-center end" id="bottom-text">
    <ul>
        <li>[</li>
        <li id="text-update>Select a Restaurant</li>
        <li>]</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm looking to update the id of "text-update".

I'm not pro in JS but if I were to do this in AS3 it would be something like this:

```
var namesArray = new Array("name-1","name-2","name-3","name-4");

var list-items-array = new Array(list-item-1,list-item-2,list-item-3,list-item-4);

for(var i = 0; i< namesArray.length; i++){
    list-items-array.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MouseOver, buttonfunction);
    list-items-array.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MouseOut, buttonfunction);
}

function buttonFunction(e:MouseEvent):void{
    // do something with the button
    text-update.text = namesArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
}
```

I've tried to create the array but the length keeps coming back with 0.

```
var listItem = $("#bottom-menu > li").toArray();
console.log(listItem.length + " this is the count");
```

I'm kind of lost as to how to set this up and get it working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your wrote this:
for(var i = 0 **l** i< namesArray.length; i++)

Don't you mean:
for(var i = 0 **;** i< namesArray.length; i++) ?

There's also a ";" missing here:
text-update.text = namesArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget)

Comment: Thanks, thats just some example code of what I want to do using javascript / jquery. I updated the mistakes I made.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are looking for, you can use the JavaScript's [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) events, like this for example :

**HTML :**

```
<div>
    <ul id="bottom-menu">
        <li><a href="#">item 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 03</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 04</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <span id="text-update">Select a Restaurant</span>
</div>
```

**Pure JavaScript :** (you can see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akmozo/Lzam0L7q/))

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#bottom-menu li a');    

for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++){
    var item = items[i];
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        setText(this.innerHTML);
    });
    item.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
        setText('Select a Restaurant');
    });
}

function setText(text){
    document.getElementById('text-update').innerHTML = text;
}
```

or using **JQuery :** (you can see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akmozo/fmqrb7jj/))

```
$.each($('#bottom-menu li a'), function(index, item){
    $(item).on('mouseover', function(){
        $('#text-update').text($(this).text());
    }).on('mouseout', function(){
        $('#text-update').text('Select a Restaurant');
    }); 
});
```

Hope that can help.